# angular ui-grid filter on button click

Tags: filter, angular-ui-grid

I'm new in angular. We are using UI-grid for data presentation is is possible to customize filter process. I want to customize it in that way, that filtering is peformmed on button click, not on keydown?
This is idea

```
$scope.search = function (){          
$scope.personCardGrid.useExternalFiltering = false; $scope.grid1Api.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL); 
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh() $scope.personCardGrid.useExternalFiltering = true;     
$scope.grid1Api.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL); 
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh() }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own headerCellTemplate for the column. In the template, add a input text box and a button too. Then, define a function in the controller and call it using the external scope which will filter the records.

Comment: But I need it for multiple parameteres, column1, column2, column3 and button for all.

Comment: Where do you want to place the input boxes? In column header or on the top of the table?

Comment: Like regualar filter field in header

Comment: Then it is better to add the button too in some column header or so. Then on click of it, call a function using external scope which filters the rows.

Comment: Ok, that is solution, but is there possibility to use ui-grid default filter. this is peace of code that isn't working$scope.search = function () {
        $scope.personCardGrid.useExternalFiltering = false;
        $scope.grid1Api.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
        $scope.gridApi.core.refresh()
        $scope.personCardGrid.useExternalFiltering = true;
        $scope.grid1Api.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
        $scope.gridApi.core.refresh()
    }